# How to connect from USB port to RJ45 console device?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hardware, fedora, router

In my Linux laptop, the USB port is connected to an external router with console port (RJ45, Juniper SRX210). This is the cable i am using:

[image]

I used cuteCom [image]
And i used minicom 
[image]

To connect using 9600 but it does not recognize /dev/ttyS0. Also tested with USBViewer (http://www.kroah.com/linux-usb/) which gives error "can not open the file /proc/bus/usb/devices"

How can i make this connection successfull? Here is my lsusb and lsusb -v

```
[root@example html]# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c05d Logitech, Inc. 


[root@example html]# lsusb -v

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength 18
  bDescriptorType 1
  bcdUSB 2.00
  bDeviceClass 9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass 0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0 64
  idVendor 0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct 0x0002 2.0 root hub
  bcdDevice 2.06
  iManufacturer 3 Linux 2.6.38.8-32.fc15.i686 ehci_hcd
  iProduct 2 EHCI Host Controller
  iSerial 1 0000:00:1d.7
  bNumConfigurations 1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength 9
    bDescriptorType 2
    wTotalLength 25
    bNumInterfaces 1
    bConfigurationValue 1
    iConfiguration 0
    bmAttributes 0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower 0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength 9
      bDescriptorType 4
      bInterfaceNumber 0
      bAlternateSetting 0
      bNumEndpoints 1
      bInterfaceClass 9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass 0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface 0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength 7
        bDescriptorType 5
        bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes 3
          Transfer Type Interrupt
          Synch Type None
          Usage Type Data
        wMaxPacketSize 0x0004 1x 4 bytes
        bInterval 12
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength 11
  bDescriptorType 41
  nNbrPorts 8
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood 10 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent 0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable 0x00 0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask 0xff 0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0100 power
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
   Port 3: 0000.0100 power
   Port 4: 0000.0100 power
   Port 5: 0000.0100 power
   Port 6: 0000.0100 power
   Port 7: 0000.0100 power
   Port 8: 0000.0100 power
Device Status: 0x0003
  Self Powered
  Remote Wakeup Enabled

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength 18
  bDescriptorType 1
  bcdUSB 1.10
  bDeviceClass 9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass 0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0 64
  idVendor 0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct 0x0001 1.1 root hub
  bcdDevice 2.06
  iManufacturer 3 Linux 2.6.38.8-32.fc15.i686 uhci_hcd
  iProduct 2 UHCI Host Controller
  iSerial 1 0000:00:1d.0
  bNumConfigurations 1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength 9
    bDescriptorType 2
    wTotalLength 25
    bNumInterfaces 1
    bConfigurationValue 1
    iConfiguration 0
    bmAttributes 0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower 0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength 9
      bDescriptorType 4
      bInterfaceNumber 0
      bAlternateSetting 0
      bNumEndpoints 1
      bInterfaceClass 9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass 0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface 0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength 7
        bDescriptorType 5
        bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes 3
          Transfer Type Interrupt
          Synch Type None
          Usage Type Data
        wMaxPacketSize 0x0002 1x 2 bytes
        bInterval 255
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength 9
  bDescriptorType 41
  nNbrPorts 2
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood 1 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent 0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable 0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask 0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0100 power
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
Device Status: 0x0003
  Self Powered
  Remote Wakeup Enabled

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength 18
  bDescriptorType 1
  bcdUSB 1.10
  bDeviceClass 9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass 0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0 64
  idVendor 0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct 0x0001 1.1 root hub
  bcdDevice 2.06
  iManufacturer 3 Linux 2.6.38.8-32.fc15.i686 uhci_hcd
  iProduct 2 UHCI Host Controller
  iSerial 1 0000:00:1d.1
  bNumConfigurations 1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength 9
    bDescriptorType 2
    wTotalLength 25
    bNumInterfaces 1
    bConfigurationValue 1
    iConfiguration 0
    bmAttributes 0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower 0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength 9
      bDescriptorType 4
      bInterfaceNumber 0
      bAlternateSetting 0
      bNumEndpoints 1
      bInterfaceClass 9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass 0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface 0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength 7
        bDescriptorType 5
        bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes 3
          Transfer Type Interrupt
          Synch Type None
          Usage Type Data
        wMaxPacketSize 0x0002 1x 2 bytes
        bInterval 255
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength 9
  bDescriptorType 41
  nNbrPorts 2
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood 1 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent 0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable 0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask 0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0303 lowspeed power enable connect
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
Device Status: 0x0003
  Self Powered
  Remote Wakeup Enabled

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength 18
  bDescriptorType 1
  bcdUSB 1.10
  bDeviceClass 9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass 0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0 64
  idVendor 0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct 0x0001 1.1 root hub
  bcdDevice 2.06
  iManufacturer 3 Linux 2.6.38.8-32.fc15.i686 uhci_hcd
  iProduct 2 UHCI Host Controller
  iSerial 1 0000:00:1d.2
  bNumConfigurations 1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength 9
    bDescriptorType 2
    wTotalLength 25
    bNumInterfaces 1
    bConfigurationValue 1
    iConfiguration 0
    bmAttributes 0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower 0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength 9
      bDescriptorType 4
      bInterfaceNumber 0
      bAlternateSetting 0
      bNumEndpoints 1
      bInterfaceClass 9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass 0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface 0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength 7
        bDescriptorType 5
        bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes 3
          Transfer Type Interrupt
          Synch Type None
          Usage Type Data
        wMaxPacketSize 0x0002 1x 2 bytes
        bInterval 255
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength 9
  bDescriptorType 41
  nNbrPorts 2
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood 1 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent 0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable 0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask 0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0100 power
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
Device Status: 0x0003
  Self Powered
  Remote Wakeup Enabled

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Device Descriptor:
  bLength 18
  bDescriptorType 1
  bcdUSB 1.10
  bDeviceClass 9 Hub
  bDeviceSubClass 0 Unused
  bDeviceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
  bMaxPacketSize0 64
  idVendor 0x1d6b Linux Foundation
  idProduct 0x0001 1.1 root hub
  bcdDevice 2.06
  iManufacturer 3 Linux 2.6.38.8-32.fc15.i686 uhci_hcd
  iProduct 2 UHCI Host Controller
  iSerial 1 0000:00:1d.3
  bNumConfigurations 1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength 9
    bDescriptorType 2
    wTotalLength 25
    bNumInterfaces 1
    bConfigurationValue 1
    iConfiguration 0
    bmAttributes 0xe0
      Self Powered
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower 0mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength 9
      bDescriptorType 4
      bInterfaceNumber 0
      bAlternateSetting 0
      bNumEndpoints 1
      bInterfaceClass 9 Hub
      bInterfaceSubClass 0 Unused
      bInterfaceProtocol 0 Full speed (or root) hub
      iInterface 0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength 7
        bDescriptorType 5
        bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes 3
          Transfer Type Interrupt
          Synch Type None
          Usage Type Data
        wMaxPacketSize 0x0002 1x 2 bytes
        bInterval 255
Hub Descriptor:
  bLength 9
  bDescriptorType 41
  nNbrPorts 2
  wHubCharacteristic 0x000a
    No power switching (usb 1.0)
    Per-port overcurrent protection
  bPwrOn2PwrGood 1 * 2 milli seconds
  bHubContrCurrent 0 milli Ampere
  DeviceRemovable 0x00
  PortPwrCtrlMask 0xff
 Hub Port Status:
   Port 1: 0000.0100 power
   Port 2: 0000.0100 power
Device Status: 0x0003
  Self Powered
  Remote Wakeup Enabled

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c05d Logitech, Inc.
Device Descriptor:
  bLength 18
  bDescriptorType 1
  bcdUSB 2.00
  bDeviceClass 0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass 0
  bDeviceProtocol 0
  bMaxPacketSize0 8
  idVendor 0x046d Logitech, Inc.
  idProduct 0xc05d
  bcdDevice 53.00
  iManufacturer 1 Logitech
  iProduct 2 USB Optical Mouse
  iSerial 0
  bNumConfigurations 1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength 9
    bDescriptorType 2
    wTotalLength 34
    bNumInterfaces 1
    bConfigurationValue 1
    iConfiguration 0
    bmAttributes 0xa0
      (Bus Powered)
      Remote Wakeup
    MaxPower 98mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength 9
      bDescriptorType 4
      bInterfaceNumber 0
      bAlternateSetting 0
      bNumEndpoints 1
      bInterfaceClass 3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass 1 Boot Interface Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol 2 Mouse
      iInterface 0
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength 9
          bDescriptorType 33
          bcdHID 1.11
          bCountryCode 0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors 1
          bDescriptorType 34 Report
          wDescriptorLength 52
         Report Descriptors:
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength 7
        bDescriptorType 5
        bEndpointAddress 0x81 EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes 3
          Transfer Type Interrupt
          Synch Type None
          Usage Type Data
        wMaxPacketSize 0x0005 1x 5 bytes
        bInterval 10
Device Status: 0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Comment: Have you plugged in the serial adapter?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Its a USB (male) cable at the end it has RJ45 male (connected to serial console port of the router which is a RJ45 female)

Comment: Your `lsusb` output doesn't show anything but a mouse plugged in. Are you sure the device on the other side is enabled for USB access like this?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Yes the device is active and its working with Windows XP from my friend pc.

Comment: Well, watch the system log as you plug the device in to see if it even gets picked up.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: How to check those plz.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: When i pull out my USB mouse it detects. But when i pull out other USB cable connected to serial external device, it shows known at all has no signal in logs. e.g: Jun 23 12:50:12 example kernel: [14237.500131] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, address 2

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Please see above, the cable i am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ttyS0` is your system's first RS232 port, you are likely looking for `ttyUSB0`

Answer (score -3):

wrong cable. this cable is for scanners. Conversion from USB signals to serial signals is done with a UART circuit embedded inside the plug. See
FTDI USB to RS232 Serial to RJ45 CAT5 Console Adapter Cable for Cisco Routers
on ebay. Then use Linux minicom program.

Comment: As there is an accepted answer, this is surely not the problem :)